# Replace a column in a SQL table, that is the result of a INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, union, inner-join

I have the following table:

```
 CodeName    cnt             cnt
CodeNAmeA   1111            2222
CodeNAmeB   3333            4444
CodeNAmeC   5555            6666
```

This table is the result of the following query:

```
(select a.CodeName, a.cnt, b.cnt from

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName) a

   JOIN

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName,tableA.INAMALOCK) b

ON a.CodeName = b.CodeName)
```

I have another table like this:

```
 CodeName        RealName
CodeNAmeA       RealNameA
CodeNAmeB       RealNameB
CodeNAmeC       RealNAmeC
```

This table is the result of a simple select query

```
select CodeName
from TableCodeReal
```

What I want to do is show the folowing:

```
 RealName    cnt     cnt
RealNameA   1111    2222
RealNameB   3333    4444
RealNameC   5555    6666
```

The problem comes that I don't have the real name in the aaaa..AAAA or bbbb..BBBB, how do I get the result of the first query and do the replacement?. Thank very much, I get very confused about how to integrate the second table in the first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you require. 
Make your main query a sub query and join onto your second table on the `CodeName` value. Then select the `RealName` from your second table, along with your `cnt` values (which I have aliased as `acnt` and `bcnt`).

```
SELECT T.RealName, Q.acnt, Q.bcnt
FROM
(select a.CodeName, a.cnt as acnt, b.cnt as bcnt from

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName) a

   JOIN

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName,tableA.INAMALOCK) b

ON a.CodeName = b.CodeName) Q
INNER JOIN TableCodeReal T ON Q.CodeName = T.CodeName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat the first record set like a virtual table. Join the record set to you second table and you can get the results you want.

```
select rt.RealName, vt.cnta, vt.cntb
from TableCodeReal rt
inner join 
(select a.CodeName, a.cnt as cnta, b.cnt as cntb from

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName) a

   JOIN

  (select tableA.CodeName, count(*) cnt
   from aaaa..AAAA tableA inner join bbbb..BBBB tableB 
   on tableA.CodeName = tableB.CodeName
   where XXXXXXX
   group by tableA.CodeName,tableA.INAMALOCK) b

ON a.CodeName = b.CodeName) vt on vt.CodeName = rt.CodeName
```

Comment: Hi!, your query is very similar to the one of Alex Tyman, but his query works and yours not. Can you explain me the difference between yours and the other answer from Alex?.

Comment: @Eduardo The only difference I can see is that the table alias he is using to get the `RealName` value is `cr` when it should be `rt`. Probably just a typo!